# SQL Server Load Distribution

Tags: sql-server, load-balancing

I need some advice. Let me tell you the scenario. Let’s say I am building a local search engine catering to users across the globe. It is not wise to store all user (businesses listed in the search engine) related data on to a single SQL Server as it might grow to a huge size. So I was thinking about storing the user login (authentication) related data on to a central server and then store other details on to different servers, each for a country or a region. For eg: I will have a SQL server each for say US, India, UK etc..

But the problem here is, If a user registers from India, his login information like username, password etc is stored in the central server and other details on to the SQL Server meant for users in India. But if the user later modifies his address details to some other country it is difficult to move all his data to the other server (his new region/country).

What I am basically trying to do is having multiple SQL Servers so that I can distribute the data on to different servers, but from a developer’s point of view how is it done normally?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (sql, server, distribution) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Couchbase. It has cross data center replication.

For your scenario, your application may need some logic. A simple one such as below may works.

1) India user register in India server
2) xdcr to central server
3) India user hit India server to change profile
4) India server modify data and xdcr back to central

OR

1) India user register in India server
2) xdcr to central server
3) India user hit Japan server to change profile
4) Japan server cannot find India user data
5) Japan server query central server for India user data
6) Japan server proceed to update queried data based on India user updates
7) Japan server store data locally
8) xdcr to central server

As such, other region servers are a subset of the central server. There is no need to replicate same data to all servers. If region servers do not have some data, query back to central server for verification.

Idea is to separate different types of data into different buckets so you can easily what data to replicate to where. Couchbase specific of course.

PS. I am not related to Couchbase.